# Necessary and sufficient conditions for all subgroups of $G\oplus H$ to be of the form $A\oplus B$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $G$ and $H$ be two groups and let $G\oplus H$ be the direct product of them. What is(are) the necessary and sufficient condition(s) for which each subgroup of the group $G\oplus H$ will be of the form $A\oplus B$, where $A$ and $B$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H$ respectively?

One necessary condition is of course that $H$ is not a subgroup of $G$ and $G$ is not a subgroup of $H$  because otherwise then we will have the [diagonal subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_subgroup) of $H\oplus H$ or $G\oplus G$, respectively; which is not of the mentioned form. But is this condition sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\phi_G:G\times H\to G$ and $\phi_H:G\times H\to H$ be the two projection maps.

Then any $K\le G\times H$ is a subdirect product of $\phi_G(K)\times\phi_H(K)$. It is the direct product required if and only if $H\cap K=\phi_H(K)$ and $G\cap K=\phi_G(K)$.

[Goursat's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma) tells us that $\phi_H(K)/(H\cap K)\cong\phi_G(K)/(G\cap K)$. So if $K$ is **not** the direct product then $G,H$ have some non-trivial isomorphic subquotients.

Conversely suppose $N\trianglelefteq K\le G$ and $M\trianglelefteq L\le H$ with $K/N$ non-trivial and an isomorphism $\phi:K/N\to L/M$. Then the set $\cup_{g\in K}(g,\phi(g)M)$ where $\phi(g)M=\{l\in L|\phi(g)=lM\}$ is a subgroup of $G\times H$ and not a direct product as described.

That is all subgroups of $G\times H$ are of the form $A\times B$ with $A\le G$, $B\le H$ if and only if $G$ and $H$ have no isomorphic subquotient.