# Let $G, H$ be finite groups. Then any subgroup of $G × H$ is equal to $A × B$ for some subgroups $A<G$ and $B<H.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Let $G, H$ be finite groups. Then any subgroup of $G × H$ is equal to $A × B$ for some subgroups $A<G$ and $B<H.$

Answer is given as False.

1. What does $A<G $means? Does it mean A is a subgroup or proper subgroup?

2.If it was proper subgroup 
MY ATTEMPT:$G × H$ is a subgroup of itself which is not equal to $A × B$  for all $A<G$ and $B<H.$

3.What if A is not a proper subgroup of G.Does it still false? If yes please give an (counter)example

Comment: Question number 9 Source: http://univ.tifr.res.in/gs2018/Files/GS2018_QP_MTH.pdf

Comment: This is almost the same question as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2890698/ from earlier today.

Comment: @Derek Holt ,i'm a noob in groups...that answer is beyond my ideas (now)

Comment: That's OK, it just seemed strange that such similar questions came at the same time, but I guess it was just coincidence in this case.

Comment: If you don't know a counterexample here, it should strike vier in your heart. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make the quantifiers in the statement a bit more precise:

> *For all* finite groups $G$ and $H$, and *for all* subgroups $K$ of $G \times H$, *there exist* subgroups $A$ of $G$ and $B$ of $H$ such that $K = A \times B$.

To show this statement is false, prove its negative:

> *There exist* finite groups $G$ and $H$, and a subgroup $K$ of $G \times H$, such that *for all* subgroups $A$ of $G$ and $B$ of $H$, $K \neq A \times B$.

You mentioned the subgroup $K = G\times H$ itself.  Notice that this subgroup is in the form $A \times B$, where $A$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $B$ is a subgroup of $H$.  Just take $A = G$ and $B=H$.  So this doesn't lead to a counterexample.

If you plot $G$ as a set of dots on the $x$-axis, and $H$ as a set of dots on the $y$-axis, then $G \times H$ is a grid of dots in the $xy$-plane.  Subgroups of the form $A \times B$ will have a “rectangular” appearance to them, since they contain every single point $(a,b)$, where $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  So try to think about a subgroup that looks more “diagonal”.

Comment: One more question(forgive me if it was crazy). How can you think like this?

Comment: @CloudJR: Not a crazy question at all, but very hard to answer.  But understanding the problem is the first big step.  Beyond that, do enough practice to be familiar with different types of finite groups.

Comment: Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 3):

A classical counterexample: let $G$ be a non-trivial group and define $D=\{(g,g): g \in G \}$. Then $D$ is a proper subgroup of $G \times G$, but certainly not a direct product of subgroups of $G$.